# Passing string variable to url on click JS

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Pass 2 string variables, 'bangor and 'lisburn' to url on click using JS.

```
<script> 
var bangor='Bangor'; 
var lisburn='Lisburn'; 
</script>

<script>    
document.write(bangor + "&nbsp>&nbsp" + lisburn)    
</script>

<a href="#">CLICK</a>
```

Comment: How is the final URL supposed to look like?

Comment: .../myroute.html?bangor+lisburn

Answer (score 0):

I would need some more information but I guess you could do something like this:

```
<a id="link" href="#">CLICK</a>

<script>
document.getElementById("link").href = bangor + "&nbsp>&nbsp" + lisburn;
</script>
```